# Multi-line text background-color with CSS cuts off characters

Tags: html, css, text, background-color

I have multi-line text content (wrapped by the browser, not delimited by `<br>`) in an HTML document and want to add a background-color highlight. My first attempt was to wrap the text I wanted to highlight in a `<span>` and style it appropriately:

```css
/* part of CSS Reset */
body { line-height: 1; }

#highlight {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <span id="highlight">dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed ipsum ut nulla tempus sodales. Aliquam augue nisl, cursus nec volutpat in, sagittis</span> in mi.
```

This renders as the following:

[image: Poor text highlighting]

Note how the bottom of characters with descenders ('g', 'p', ',') are cutoff where they appear to be overlapped by the background of the next line.

I tried to fix this with a transparent background, but it only served to better demonstrate the overlap:

```css
/* part of CSS Reset */
body { line-height: 1; }

#highlight {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <span id="highlight">dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed ipsum ut nulla tempus sodales. Aliquam augue nisl, cursus nec volutpat in, sagittis</span> in mi.
```

[image: same as above, but with a transparent background that is darker between lines]

Alternatively, increasing the `line-height` seems to work:

```css
#highlight {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <span id="highlight">dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed ipsum ut nulla tempus sodales. Aliquam augue nisl, cursus nec volutpat in, sagittis</span> in mi.
```

However, I need a way to fix this overlap issue without visually increasing the spacing between lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix that I found is to wrap the text in a second `<span>` and style that with `position: relative`. The outer span renders the background color in the same position, and then the inner span renders the text on top of it.

```css
/* part of CSS Reset */
body { line-height: 1; }

#highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}

#highlight > span {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <span id="highlight"><span>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed ipsum ut nulla tempus sodales. Aliquam augue nisl, cursus nec volutpat in, sagittis</span></span> in mi.
```

[image: highlighted lines without any cutoff characters]

Edit: Note how the "p" in "ipsum" is cut off. This can be fixed with even more `<span>`s:

```css
/* part of CSS Reset */
body { line-height: 1; }

#highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}

#highlight > span {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.no-highlight {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="no-highlight">Lorem ipsum </span><span id="highlight"><span>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed ipsum ut nulla tempus sodales. Aliquam augue nisl, cursus nec volutpat in, sagittis</span></span> in mi.
```

Comment: still cuts off the 'p' in ipsum.